# Why div element inside container doesn't occupy 12 columns by default but only 1?

Tags: html, css, .net, bootstrap-4

I'm having troubles understanding bootstrap's grid system, based on **Murach's .Net** book explanation.

Please read the whole post, I know how to fix this (`<div class="col-lg-12">Col x</div>`, does the trick), I'm just wondering why bootstrap works this way.

I did copy an example from a book, where `Column a` and `Column b` should use the 12 columns that bootstraps provides to work with its grid system, or that's what I got from the book, at least. Also, this very same code

```
<main class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>Column a</div>
        <div>Column b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Column c</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">Column d</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Column e</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">Column f</div>
    </div>
</main>
```

outputs those `div`s occupying the 12 columns in the book's screenshot (First `Column 1` and `Column 2` "group" are `Column a` and `Column b` in my code).

[image]

But this is what I get from it

[image]

unless of course I apply the trick I said earlier in the post.

This is what I specified in the `head` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap/min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is `style.css`:

```
.container 
{
    padding-top:1em;
}
.row 
{
    margin-bottom: 2em ;
}
.row div
{
    border: 1px solid black ;
    padding: 0.5em ;
    background-color:lightgrey ;
}
```

Comment: you need to apply your col class to the first 2 divs otherwise they will have no width and only be as wide as their content (as they are inside a parent with display flex)

Comment: @Pete Well, as I said, I can fix this by doing that. The book says container uses the 12 columns that bootstrap provides, then I wouln't have to do it, I also tried using container-fluid with no luck. Is it not how the book says and every div inside a container would only occupy 1 column?

Comment: Is the book talking about bootstrap 3 as that works differently to bootstrap 4 - if you paid attention to the bit in brackets of my comment that is the main reason - bootstrap 3 uses floats, while bootstrap 4 uses flex.

Comment: @Pete now that you mention it, yes it is!

Comment: You should use the actual docs rather than out of date books: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @Pete you are right, it's not a book about bootstrap, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the DIV's is based on flexbox. The Bootstrap 4 `row` class is `display:flex`, so when you have a simple DIV inside it simply follows [default flexbox behavior](https://www.codeply.com/go/qvHVlTJshv). This isn't 1 column unit, it simply takes the width of the content since neither grow or shrink is specified.

The Bootstrap 4 `col-*` classes have specific properties design to work inside the parent `row`.. such as flex-basis, max-width, padding, etc...

https://www.codeply.com/go/qvHVlTJshv

Read more in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
>   (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
>   is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins... In a grid
>   layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows"